# HTML AND PHP not working

Tags: php, html, contact-form

Hi All i am trying to get my contacts page working i have input all the date but when i click on submit it just displays the php code on the next page. WHat am i doing wrong.

**HTML Code**:

```
        <form method="post" name="contact" action="php\html_form_send.php">

                <label for="name">Name:</label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="required input_field" />
                <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

                <label for="email">Email:</label> <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="validate-email required input_field" />
                <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

                <label for="telephone">Telephone:</label> <input type="number" name="telephone" id="telephone" class="input_field" />

                <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

                <label for="subject">Subject:</label> <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="input_field" />

                <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

                <label for="text">Message:</label> <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="0" cols="0" class="required"></textarea>
                <div class="cleaner h10"></div>

                        <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" name="Submit" class="submit_btn float_l" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset" name="reset" class="submit_btn float_r" />

                </form>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "info@*********.com";

    $email_subject = "website html form submissions";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['subject']) ||
        !isset($_POST['text'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $text = $_POST['text']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$subject)) {
    $error_message .= 'The subject you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($text) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The text you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($subject)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "text: ".clean_string($text)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
die();
?>

</body>
```

**ERROR**

```
"; echo $error."

    "; echo "Please go back and fix these errors.

    "; die(); } // validation expected data exists if(!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['email']) || !isset($_POST['telephone']) || !isset($_POST['subject']) || !isset($_POST['text'])) { died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.'); } $name = $_POST['name']; // required $subject = $_POST['subject']; // required $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required $text = $_POST['text']; // required $error_message = ""; $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/'; if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) { $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.
    '; } $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/"; if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) { $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.
    '; } if(!preg_match($string_exp,$subject)) { $error_message .= 'The subject you entered does not appear to be valid.
    '; } if(strlen($text) < 2) { $error_message .= 'The text you entered do not appear to be valid.
    '; } if(strlen($error_message) > 0) { died($error_message); } $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n"; function clean_string($string) { $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href"); return str_replace($bad,"",$string); } $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n"; $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($subject)."\n"; $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n"; $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n"; $email_message .= "text: ".clean_string($text)."\n"; // create email headers $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n". 'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); ?> Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
```

Comment: Does your hoster support php?

Comment: What is it displaying? "the php code" isn't very descriptive. Are you saying that your web server isn't actually executing the PHP code and just displays it as raw text? How did you set up your web server?

Comment: You should place your process PHP before any HTML in the document, as a start, and make sure nothing is printed to the page before you set your headers

Comment: @Intergolactic There are no HTTP headers in this post - that part wouldn't make a difference (although I agree that PHP shouldn't be mixed with HTML in this way).

Comment: Not that we can see...

Comment: If you doing this locally are you looking at the file or the webserver? ie file://c:\wwwroot\index.php or http:// localhost/index.php. Is apache or IIS running??

Answer (score 2):

The PHP code is not beeing compiled. It's been served as a plain file. Check your PHP installation.